# Filesystemobject Textstream, immediately disappears upon executing Textstream.Close (.vbs extension being created)

Tags: vba, antivirus, group-policy, filesystemobject

I have a situation that is really flummoxing me. Simple code I've used for years is failing in the weirdest way.  I have a feeling the cause is related to either anti-virus junk or GPO, but, even those, I have seen them operate before on this scenario--but nothing like how I am seeing it now.
**Note - this code has been working perfectly for several people, until one end-user got a new Surface laptop from I.T., purportedly for better compatibility with Teams and 365.  ALL users (working, non-working) are on Windows 10.**

Scenario:

1. I'm using Scripting.Filesystemobject
2. setting an object variable (Textstream intent), as fso.createtextfile
3. The filepath (name) I am creating is actually filename.vbs...At the moment this line executes, I can see the vbs file successfully in the folder
4. I use Textstream.Write to put some content in the file
5. I then use Textstream.Close (normally at this point you get a solid, stable, useable file).  **Immediately upon execution of the last line, Textstream.Close, the file DISAPPEARS from the folder-GONE.**

The folder I'm writing to is the same as Start > Run > %appdata%
I've also tried this in Documents folder (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents") and get the exact same result

I've seen group policies and AV stuff that will prevent VBS from running, but that isn't my case--I've tested with this user, and she has no problem:

1. Creating a txt file in either of those folders
2. Manually creating a .vbs file in either of those folders
3. Even RUNNING the resulting vbs file in either folder

But somehow when I programmatically create .VBS in code, the second I close the textstream, the file is gone from the folder.

Any insight?  The internet searches I did were void of all information on this scenario!!  It would take me 2 weeks to open a ticket and get any help from I.T.

This is Excel VBA, but I highly doubt the problem has anything to do with Excel nor VBA...this is standard usage of windows scripting.filesystemobject:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'initiate full backup vbs script:
Dim ts As Object, fso As Object, strScriptText As String, strScriptPath As String
'populate our variable with the full text of the script: found on QLoader in this range:
strScriptText = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QLoader").Range("z_BackupScriptText").Value
'replace the text "placeholder" with this workbook's actual full path/name:
strScriptText = Replace(strScriptText, "placeholder", ThisWorkbook.FullName)

'fire up FSO:
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
'determine the new VBS file's path
strScriptPath = Environ("AppData") & "\Backup_" & Format(Now, "yymmddhhmmss") & ".vbs"
'create our textstream object:
Set ts = fso.createtextfile(strScriptPath)
'write our script into it
ts.write strScriptText
'save and close it
ts.Close 'RIGHT HERE THE FILE DISAPPEARS FROM THE FOLDER ***********

'GO:
Shell "wscript " & strScriptPath, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like an antivirus thing...

If the issue is just the `vbs` extension though, you can use something like this:

```vb
Sub tester()

    Dim ts As Object, fso As Object, strScriptText As String, strScriptPath As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    strScriptPath = Environ("AppData") & "\Backup_" & Format(Now, "yymmddhhmmss") & ".txt"
    
    Set ts = fso.createtextfile(strScriptPath)
    
    ts.write "Msgbox ""Hello"""
    
    ts.Close
    
    'need to specify the script engine to use
    Shell "wscript.exe /E:vbscript """ & strScriptPath & """ ", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my!  That looks like a great solution option I hadn't known about.  I was in the process of doing this approach--if it will allow me to create a .txt file, then rename the file (haven't tested w/user yet), but yours is very good to know, I'll try it and post back, thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to use vbscript here?  Typically you can use VBA for the same tasks...

Comment: Very fair question.  In this case here is the need:  To provide a very simple, invisible, method of creating a "full" backup, of an Excel workbook.  Without creating any other files or shortcuts that the user has to initiate.  So the way I've solved this is to, in the workbook close event, have VBA create the VBScript file (which itself contains a 40-second wait - and then copies the same Excel file that fired it off), and then begin running the vbs file as it closes.

Comment: You could use `SaveCopyAs` inside the event to do that.

Comment: All I can come up with is:  "WOW."  For some reason, in 15 years of VBA, I have totally missed that.  Feeling stupid!  Have no idea how I missed it, but did not know about that.  Thank you!  You're right - that would absolutely be the way to go.  I'm very glad you taught me what you did about shelling cscript, though - Valuable stuff.  Thanks again.

Comment: I mean wscript.